# Opencenus prevent my java process from exiting

Tags: jenkins, jmeter, opencensus

I am using opencensus in my component, I am running a performance test with JMeter started by Jenkins, but the process never ends and I discovered that it is opencenus that is keeping it alive (because if I remove opencenus the process finishes/dies normally).

Is there anything I can do in opencenus, Jenkins or JMeter to force the job to finish? Aborting the job also does not help as per Jenkins do not collect the results then.

Answer (score 1):

IIRC, there's nothing inherent in OpenCensus that would cause this.

Caveat: I've mostly used OpenCensus with Golang, Python and JavaScript but not Java.

However, if, for example, you're using the Prometheus Exporter, it's common to run this in a separate thread because the e.g. Prometheus server needs to scrape (via HTTP) a metrics endpoint that's exposed by your component.

Could it be that it is this that's keeping your component alive?

If so, there should be a mechanism to gracefully terminate the Exporter once your component is done with it.

zPages and possibly other Exporters take this background thread approach too.

Comment: I am exposing prometheus metrics, but currently, I do not actually have prometheus scrapping it. I may try to remove the exporter for a test when I get a chance.

Comment: I looked into this for you. It appears that the Prometheus Exporter uses `java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService` and, while there is a `stop` method and this calls `executorService.shutdown()` that provides no guarantee that the executor will terminate . There may be a way to force this. Alternatively, perhaps ping the repo and ask for help. https://github.com/prometheus/client_java/blob/ef16c43f63128c14627eeff301a32c12e7751a4e/simpleclient_httpserver/src/main/java/io/prometheus/client/exporter/HTTPServer.java#L236